# apply user defined function to pandas dataframe specific columns and add new columns to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I created a function called `polar(X_relative , Y_relative , Z_relative)` that takes these 3 arguments as shown and the result are new arguments which are `(azimuth_angle , tilt_angle)`.
I want to apply this function to a pandas dataframe where the function arguments are certain columns in the dataframe and would like to add the output arguments of the functions `(azimuth_angle , tilt_angle)` as new coulmns in the dataframe where the function is calculated for each row.

```
dataframe columns: X , Y, Z , X_relative , Y_relative , Z_relative
dataframe coulmns I expect after applying the function: X , Y, Z , X_relative , Y_relative , Z_relative , azimuth_angle , tilt_angle
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the return of `polar` into a series:

```
return pd.Series([azimuth_angle, tilt_angle])
```

Then use `apply`:

```
df[['azimuth_angle', 'tilt_angle']] = df.apply(lambda x: polar(x.X_relative, x.Y_relative, x.Z_relative), axis = 1)
```

Comment: when I run this this error occurs:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Right. This is made a bit more complex by your function returning two things. If you could split it into two fns each returning one you could use apply:
`df['azimuth_angle'] = df.apply(lambda x: polar(x.X_relative, x.Y_relative, x.Z_relative), axis = 1)`

Comment: Alternatively wrap the return of `polar` into a series - `return pd.Series([azimuth_angle, tilt_angle])` - and then call `df[['azimuth_angle', 'tilt_angle']] = df.apply(lambda x: polar(x.X_relative, x.Y_relative, x.Z_relative), axis = 1)`